# Lazy loading angular module with ES6 and systemjs.import

Tags: angularjs, jspm, systemjs

I am trying to have a base route and lazy load the separate modules with angular resolve with system.load.I Am using jspm with ES6 module loader

The base route config goes like this

```
import "angular";
import "angular-ui-router";

class RouteConfig {

    constructor($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
        this.stateProvider = $stateProvider;
        this.urlRouterProvider = $urlRouterProvider;

        $stateProvider
            .state("index", {
                url: "/",
                templateUrl: "/app/common/templates/home.html",
            })
            .state('order',{
                url:'/order',
                templateUrl:"/app/modules/order/templates/order.html",
                //controller:"order.controller as orderCtrl",
                resolve:{
                    load:()=>{
                        System.import('app/modules/order/order.module');
                        System.import('app/modules/order/order.controller');
                    }
                }
            });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
    };

    static factory($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
        RouteConfig.instance = new RouteConfig($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider);   
        return RouteConfig.instance;
    };
}

RouteConfig.factory.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];

export default RouteConfig;
```

Now I am trying to lazy load the controller based on the module necessary . 
So the module and controller loads as

import "angular";
import "angular-ui-router";

```
class OrderModule {

    constructor($log,$stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
        //$stateProvider
        //    .state('order',{

        //    })

    }

    static factory($log){
        OrderModule.instance = new OrderModule($log,$stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider);
        return OrderModule.instance;
    }
}

angular.module("order.module", ['ui.router']);
OrderModule.factory.$inject = ['$log','$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider'];
export default  OrderModule;
```

And controller

```
"use strict";

class OrderController {
    constructor() {
        this.order = "Please place an order";
    }
    static factory() {
        OrderController.instance = new OrderController();
        return OrderController.instance;
    }

}

angular.module('order.module').controller('Order.Controller', OrderController);

export default OrderController;
```

Now when I am trying this . This gives me error as

[image]

Can someone tell how to load this module . It seems that the angular module file is loaded through systemjs but its not registering angular module . Any solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
System.import('app/modules/order/order.module')
    .then(function () {
        System.import('app/modules/order/order.controller');
    });
```

inside `load()` `resolve`